# Merging two list from different WCF ServiceClients which have the same object-type

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, webforms

I have a class library which contains a class called "Club" which is used by two WCF Services. These each have a method with the same return type, a list of Club-objects: `List<Club>`.

When I call both methods in a webform I get back two lists with these Club-objects however I cannot merge those lists with the help of Concat since one list is seen as serviceClient1.`List<Club>` and the other one is seen as serviceClient2.List and not just `List<Club>`.

```
  var resultService1 = service1Client.GetClubByName(search).ToList();
  var resultService2 = service2Client.GetClubByName(search).ToList();
  var endResult = resultService1.Concat(resultService2);
```

I've tried casting and changing var with a the specific object-type but with no result. How would I be able to fix it because I want to show the results from both services in one grid.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `resultService1.Concat(resultService2).ToList()` or `resultService1.AddRange(resultService2)`?

Comment: Concat doesn't seem to work since it aren't IEnumerable's and AddRange gives the "Not assignable to parameter type" error.

Comment: So they are actually not the same type?

Comment: They are based on the same type but each service gives them back as a servicename.List<object-type>.

Comment: Do you need all properties from the Club?

Comment: Yes, the merged list will be used as a datasource for the grid to show all properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to create a new anonymous type that contains the properties you need.

```
var endResult = resultService1
                  .Select(x => new { x.Prop1, x.Prop2})
                  .Concat(resultService2
                           .Select(x => new { x.Prop1, x.Prop2}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, they are not the same (namespace + class name). And the fact that they are returned by different service also "indicates" that they are not the "same". And even if they have the same shape (list of properties) today, there is not guarantee that they will change soon (do you control the services?).

With that said, you could solve this by creating extension methods client side to convert from one Club class to another. Or convert them manually (loop or linq).

Comment: Both services are mine yes, these are mainly for testing purposes and won't be used in real life applications.

Comment: OK, I see. If you end up with this kind of "problem" I would go for a different service architecture then wcf. In a REST context this would not be a problem. Otherwise I think Mangus approach would work - unless you need to pass the class between assembly boarders...

Comment: I will definitely keep that in mind, atm I'm learning WCF so wanted to try it out. Thanks for the suggestion!